# django schemamigration creates the same migration change

Tags: django, django-south, migrate

I messed up merging schema migrations from multiple git branches.

Basically, all the changes are applied to DB, but when I do

```
python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
```

It recreates migration file for all the changes which were recently applied.

How can I fix this?

(I tried to be smart while combining branches and run --delete-ghost-migrations and replay them.. without understanding what I was doing fully) :(

Comment: if it recreates all the migrations again. Then you can fake them one by one. `python manage.py migrate myapps 0001 --fake` and `python manage.py migrate myapps 0002 --fake` so and so for. Because migrations are already applied right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think happened.

I have a branch which I branched off from upstream/master.
This doesn't have database schema changes I have in my local git repo.
I worked on this branch and merged to my local branch.

Now the migration files from the merged-in branch don't have latest schema changes in the migrations files. (Yes that's what it think is current status of DB, and compare it to my models.py files. This was the key to solve the problem.)

Below is simplified view of what happened.

> 003 -- change made in local branch
>   004 -- change made in branch(from upstream/master) and doesn't have changes introduced in 003

When I run schemamigration it creates

> 005 -- reapplies the changes in 003

and run migrate, and fails.

I fixed the problem by modifying the contents of migrations files manually.

Answer (score 3):

Try to:

**python manage.py migrate your_app_name**
to ensure you've got no changes that aren't already in the migrations

and than:

**python manage.py schemamigration --empty your_app_name name_of_migration**
will make an empty migration but which has up-to-date info in it.